# How to show using Cauchy integral formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let f(z) be an entire function such that  $\;|f(z)| \le M|z|^n\;$ for any $\;z ∈ \Bbb C\; , \;\text{and}\;M >0\;$ is a fixed number. Using Cauchy integral formula, show that for any

$$\;k\ge n+1\;,\;\; f^{(k)}(0)=0 \;\;and\;\; f^{(k)}(z_0) = 0\;$$

I am having hard time with this question. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry in advance if formatting is wrong.

Comment: What is $\;z_0\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

For any $r$, let $\gamma_r$ be the path $\gamma_r(\theta)=re^{i\theta}$. Because $f$ is entire, we have
$$\begin{align*}
|f^{(k)}(0)|&=\frac{k!}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{k+1}}\,dz\right|\\\\
&\leq\frac{k!}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{k+1}}\,dz\\\\
&\leq\frac{k!}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{M|z|^n}{|z|^{k+1}}\,dz\\\\
&\leq\frac{M\cdot k!}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma_r}\frac{1}{|z|^{k+1-n}}\,dz\\\\
&=(\text{some constant})\cdot \frac{1}{r^{\text{ something positive}}}
\end{align*}$$
Because this is true for any $r$, we must have $f^{(k)}(0)=0$.

Now prove that if $|f(z)|\leq M|z|^n$ for some $n$, then for any $z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ there is some $L$ such that $$|f(z-z_0)|\leq L|z-z_0|^n$$
and then modify the argument, or use the same argument on the new function $g(z)=f(z-z_0)$.